# Discord.py on_command_error cooldown is triggered, but does not send the embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have tried to put the error handler in a try/except block, yet it responds with no embed, then i've put the try/except on the command which I'm calling, and still, nothing. Command executes successfully, and it triggers the cooldown for 10 seconds, but does not send an embed. It worked just fine before, but a week ago or so it just snapped and stopped working.

The on_command_error:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Error!", description=f"This command is on cooldown, you can use it in {round(error.retry_after, 2)} seconds!.", color=discord.Color.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The command I am calling(I have also tried capturing the CommandOnCooldown exception and passing it to the on_command_error, and yet, no embed):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
async def scrungler(ctx):
    await ctx.send("<:scrungler:1082698194502287400>")
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure this isn't an intents issue/discord app portal?

Comment: All of my intents are enabled in the code and in my discord developer portal, as I said, it worked just fine a week ago, and without any changes to intents, the cooldown command stopped working. I can share the whole code for my discord bot, but its 700 lines long

Comment: The command itself stopped working? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that my discord bot did not stop the on_command_error function from executing instead it does not send me any embed when the CommandOnCooldown  is triggered in the on_command_error

Comment: I find this problem really weird, since the only changes I've made is add new commands to my bot, I did not touch on_command_error in any way